# How can I get a formulas array?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-dna

It's possible to get an array of values for a multi-cell selection:

```
var reference = new ExcelReference(i1, i2, j1, j2);
var vals = reference.GetValue();
```

However, a call to `XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlfGetFormula)` return a single cell's formula only. Is there any way to get an array of formulas for all the cells in the selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel does not have a way to get the formula for more than one cell at once.

Comment: i.e. the only way is to iterate a range and get the fomula for every cell?

Comment: That's the only way if you're using the C API or the COM object model. Maybe there's a way using the clipboard to get the formulas, or maybe you could read and process the file in some other way. Those approaches won't be straight-forward, though.